# Fast Wi-Fi speed on smartphone but slow on notebook

Tags: wireless-networking, router, performance

I have a  Lenovo G710 notebook and a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 smartphone  connecting to a Linksys E1200 AP.

The Wi-Fi speed on my G710 is extremely slow compared to the Note 3, and half of a month on, the problem still exists.

I checked the speed via [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net/), and the results are:

G710 notebook:
ping = 3ms
download speed = 7.01Mbps
upload speed = 13.92Mbps

Note 3 smartphone:
ping = 3ms
download speed = 35.23Mbps
upload speed = 24.13Mbps

My notebook's specifications:
OS: Windows 8.1 (64bit)
CPU: Intel Core i704712mq cpu @ 2.39GHz 2.29GHz
RAM: 8GB
Network interface card: Broadcom 802.11n network adapter
(with one other card, not sure what it is: Qualcomm Atheros AR8172/8176/8178 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller(NDIS6.30) )

For the driver, I went to the Lenovo site and searched for the wireless driver for G710, but it seems no driver is provided by Lenovo. Also same case for Linksys E1200.

Comment: You can find the latest wifi driver here: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g710-notebook?c=1%29

Comment: The other device driver you mentioned (AR8172/8176/8178 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller) controls the ethernet port.

Comment: Are you sure you testing the speed of your network on the phone and not the speed your provider because 35.23Mbps on a 802.11n is extremely fast.  I want to say its to fast for 802.11n

Comment: @Ramhound You must be thinking of 802.11g. If you do 802.11n with 3 spatial streams, 40MHz-wide channels, and short guard intervals, you get a 450Mbps PHY rate. Use A-MPDU frame aggregation for max efficiency of maybe 80%, and you could see 360Mbps out of 802.11n. In fact 35Mbps would not even quite be "too much" for even the wimpiest flavor of 802.11n (65Mbps PHY rate). Or maybe you were thinking of mebibytes/sec instead of megabits/sec?

Comment: @user3026820 Does your G710 have Bluetooth enabled? Try disabling Bluetooth as a test and see if you get better performance. Can you find the exact model number of the Broadcom chipset in your particular revision/config of the G710?

Comment: thx for the comments. @PFitz, there are no wireless driver for win8.1, should I download the win8 versions?

Comment: @Spiff, I have tried the disable the bluetooth, but seem not different on the speed. And how should I look up for the chipest model number?

Comment: I have already uninstall and re-install the wifi drive, but problem still exist